# Import Spring configurations(*.xml) from dependent packages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi we are developing a web stack, we have the main package(tomcat container) lets call it A, which is dependent of 4 other packages B, C, D, E. All of the packages are using spring for dependency injection and we write the spring configuration using Xmls.

Now we have declared the dependencies of A on B,c,D,E but aren't able to import the spring configs which they have defined in their source. I am able to do that if I use java based annotated-configurations for defining spring configs. But i wondering if there is way to do it with Xmls.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify your question? I don't get it.

The are four cases and let me cover all of them:

1. If you want to use `xml` configuration in `java` configuration you need to use

   ```
   @ImportResource("classpath:path-to-your.xml")
   ```

   construction for `@Configuration` class.
2. If you want to import `xml` into other `xml` then you have to use

   ```
   <import resource="path-to-your-xml.xml" />
   ```
3. If you want to use `java` config in `xml` config then use:

   ```
   <bean class="package.YourConfig" />
   ```
4. The last case is when you want to import `java` config in other `java` config. Then simply use `@Import(YourConfig.clas)` annotation